# python how to create a new array, list or even a new column with objects from an array, list or column with a set criteria

Tags: python, arrays

So, I'm using python and I want to explore the Titanic data set.

I want compare the number of people in each "Pclass" (1st class, 2nd Class 3rd Class) with who survived(1) and did not survive(0).

I can't even return the number of people who survived(1) and did not survive(0) out of the total population.

```
print(len(train['Survived'] == 1))
```

Why does this return 891(the total population)? Shouldn't it only print the number of people who survived?

Comment: How should we know that. Where is your code?

Comment: please see [ask] and consider providing an [mcve]

Comment: This `print(len(train['Survived'] == 1)) ` will just produce an error. You're trying to get the length of a boolean value.

Comment: I think he made a type while writing that, because the OP states that it already return a value of 891

Comment: If you didn't know what I was talking about, then I wouldn't expect you to be able to answer the question - like @dhdavvie did just amazingly. As for the error: No, it doesn't produce an error. It produces the total number of objects in train['Survived'], which is 891. Like I said.

Comment: @PatrickGalt Your code on your computer might produce 891. The code you posted here produces an error.

Comment: There's nothing 'brilliant' about dhdavvie's answer, you provided essentially zero information about your problem, and he made a lucky guess. NB: If you come here often and expect people to "know what you're talking about" without providing enough information, you're going to have a bad time...

Comment: Doing pretty good so far. There was no obligation for you to answer the question. dhdavvie's answer was brilliant in that he used common sense and general experience in order to elucidate on my very simple and easy to answer question. You failed to do this. But, that's ok, don't take it personally. Keep at it bud, I'm sure you'll be able to answer somebody's question someday just like dhdavvie did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
print(len([x for x in train['Survived'] if x == 1]))
```

For more info, check out [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: Thank you for your brilliance.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
print(len(train['Survived'] == 1))
```

will just produce an error. `train['Survived'] == 1` is a boolean, and you can't take the length of a boolean.

If you want to count the number times 1 occurs in the list `train['Survived']`, then you could write:

```
print(sum(x==1 for x in train['Survived']))
```

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is generally the best way to count matches in a list, because it doesn't require you to construct a new list just to take the length.

Comment: I just found it odd because:

Comment: I just found it odd because this is working:


`first_class_not_survived = train[(train.Survived == 0) & (train.Pclass == 1)]`
`first_class_survived = train[(train.Survived == 1) & (train.Pclass == 1)]`


When I print the len() of these variables, it gives me the correct count, which I now know is correct after having used the code you provided. My code returns: 80 dead vs 136 survived, plus using your code (pclass in lieu of survived), a Pclass count of: 216.